# Based on String in one column convert one row in to multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to convert the one row into multiple rows based on the numeric values in string in one column

Example input:

```
EmpId | work date  | String 
------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------
 1234 | 12/10/2020 | The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters
```

Example output:

```
Empid | Work Date  | Clock | Radius 
------+------------+-------+--------
1234  | 12/10/2020 | 12:03 | 209759
1234  | 12/10/2020 | 12:04 | 209758
```

There can be n numbers of values based on the numbers in string it has to split into two columns and rows.

Please help me with this - thank you

Comment: Please provide the rules for this.  For instance, `12:03` is not a "numeric value" as I would define "numeric".  Are there always two of them?  What if there are multiple groups?  And why are you using an unsupported verson of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL is really bad at string manipulation like this. Do it in C# or such like. Better idea, put it in the database in separate rows and column in the first place

Comment: Hi , I am new to Microsoft Sql server. the server version  which i am using is 15 there will be  many not limited to two  there will be more in a string . i need to split it based on the , and it has to show in two seperated columns

Comment: If you know the text is always of the form `The following clocks [list of times] are outside of the allowed radius by [list of integers] meters` then it's quite doable in T-SQL, by use of `CHARINDEX` and any number of well-known string split approaches if `STRING_SPLIT` isn't available. For any pattern more general than that it gets iffy. I agree with the others that you are much better off identifying the process that generates this text in the first place, and making it produce rows instead of text.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is messy, but working:

1. First CTE is tokenizing **free_text** columns via XML and XQuery, and filters out tokens without
   a comma.
2. 2nd CTE is getting **clock** column out of XML.
3. 3rd CTE is getting **Radius** column out of XML.
4. Final SELECT brings it all together.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (emp_id INT, work_date DATE, free_text NVARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @tbl (emp_id, work_date, free_text) VALUES
(1234, '12/10/2020',N'The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1)
    , @comma CHAR(1) = ',';

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT emp_id, work_date
        , CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
            REPLACE(free_text COLLATE Czech_BIN2, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r></root>' AS XML)
        .query('
        for $x in /root/r
        where contains($x, sql:variable("@comma"))
        return $x
        ') AS result
    FROM @tbl
), clock AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
        , rs.*
        , z.value AS clock
    FROM rs
        CROSS APPLY result.nodes('/r[1]') AS t(c)
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'), @comma) AS z
), Radius AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS seq
        , rs.*
        , z.value AS Radius
    FROM rs
        CROSS APPLY result.nodes('/r[2]') AS t(c)
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(20)'), @comma) AS z
)
SELECT c.emp_id, c.work_date, c.clock, r.Radius
FROM clock AS c
    INNER JOIN Radius AS r ON r.seq = c.seq
        AND r.emp_id = c.emp_id;
```

**Output**

```
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
| emp_id | work_date  | clock | Radius |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
|   1234 | 2020-12-10 | 12:03 | 209759 |
|   1234 | 2020-12-10 | 12:04 | 209758 |
+--------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Another messy one - without XML - but using a borrowed "Tally" table solution - which may prove useful for performance if source data volumes are High

Thank you Yitzhak Khabinsky as his version absolutely valid and probably simpler to maintain - I got lost with my XML version so went to a tally table. Just a caution of the solution from Yitzhak, if there are more radius readings supplied than clock readings supplied - we won't know about it from the results directly- the entire record is excluded.

Here is my (long winded perhaps) solution

**Step 1) Build a Tally table**

**Step 2) Build a tabular function that ties and converts a delimited value into a table with a rownum**

**Step 3 - Deploy a a tabular function that parses the string accordingly and returns a table with converted records**

**Step 4 Test Cases - and example usage**

**Step 5 - Modify the main function to hide all columns right of Column "Radius"**

**Step 1) Build a Tally table**
From https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1

```
--=============================================================================
--      Setup Tally Table
--=============================================================================
    USE TempDB     --DB that everyone has where we can cause no harm
    SET NOCOUNT ON --Supress the auto-display of rowcounts for appearance/speed
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME    --Timer to measure total duration
    SET @StartTime = GETDATE() --Start the timer
--=============================================================================
--      Create and populate a Tally table
--=============================================================================
--===== Conditionally drop and create the table/Primary Key
     IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Tally') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE dbo.Tally
 CREATE TABLE dbo.Tally 
        (N INT, 
         CONSTRAINT PK_Tally_N PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (N))
--===== Create and preset a loop counter
DECLARE @Counter INT
    SET @Counter = 1
--===== Populate the table using the loop and couner
  WHILE @Counter <= 11000
  BEGIN
         INSERT INTO dbo.Tally
                (N)
         VALUES (@Counter)
            SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
    END
--===== Display the total duration
 SELECT STR(DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,GETDATE())) + ' Milliseconds duration'
```

**Step 2) Build a tabular function that ties and converts a delimited value into a table with a rownum**
This will ensure even if there are hundreds of radius and clock readings - each will be converted to a sub-table quickly.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%e2%80%9ccsv-splitter%e2%80%9d-function

Function uses tally table created in Step 1

```
create function [dbo].[SplitAndSequence] (@pString nvarchar(4000), @pDelimiter char(1)) returns table return
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.N),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, t.N, CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter, @pString + @pDelimiter, t.N) - t.N)
   FROM TempDB.dbo.Tally t
  WHERE t.N <= DATALENGTH(@pString)+1 --DATATLENGTH allows for trailing space delimiters
    AND SUBSTRING(@pDelimiter + @pString, t.N, 1) = @pDelimiter
```

**Step 3 - Deploy a a tabular function that parses the string accordingly and returns a table with converted records**

```
CREATE function [dbo].[fn_ParseAndReturnObservations] (@Emp_ID varchar(50), @WorkDateStr varchar(10), @String nvarchar(300)) returns table 
-- select * from [fn_ParseAndReturnObservations]('1234', '12/10/2020', 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters')
return
with [cte_SourceData] as (
select [Emp_ID] = @Emp_Id -- '1234'
     , [Work Date] = convert(date,@WorkDateStr,103) -- convert(date,'12/10/2020',103)
     , [String] = @String -- 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters'
) -- end [cte_SourceData]
, [cte_Parse1] as (
select [Emp_ID], [Work Date]
     , [Clocks Position] = charindex('clocks ', [String]) + len('clocks')
     , [String] 
  from [cte_SourceData] 
)  -- end [cte_Parse1]
, [cte_Parse2] as (
select [Emp_ID], [Work Date] , [Clocks Position]
     , [String From Clock Observations] = substring([String],[Clocks Position]+1, len([String]))
     , [String]
  from [cte_Parse1]
)  -- end [cte_Parse2]
, [cte_Parse3] as (
select [Emp_ID], [Work Date]
     , [Clock Observations] = substring([String From Clock Observations],1, charindex(' ',[String From Clock Observations])-1)
     , [Clocks Position], [String From Clock Observations]
     , [Radius Verbosity Position Pre Ends] = charindex(' are outside of the allowed radius by ', [String From Clock Observations]) + len(' are outside of the allowed radius by ')
         --- Assumes no spaces between Clock Observations
     , [String]
  from [cte_Parse2]
) -- end [cte_Parse3]
, [cte_Parse4] as (
select [Emp_ID], [Work Date], [Clock Observations]
     , [String From Meters] = substring([String From Clock Observations],[Radius Verbosity Position Pre Ends]+1,len([String From Clock Observations]))
     , [Clocks Position] , [String From Clock Observations], [String]
  from [cte_Parse3]
) -- end [cte_Parse4]
, [cte_ReadyForDelimiting] as (
select [Emp_ID], [Work Date], [Clock Observations]
     , [Radius Observations] = substring([String From Meters],1, charindex(' meters', [String From Meters]))
--     , [String From Meters]     , [Clocks Position] , [String From Clock Observations], [String]
  from [cte_Parse4]
) -- end [cte_ReadyForDelimiting] 
, [cte_CountNumberOfSubColumns] as (
select [rdy].[Emp_ID], [rdy].[Work Date], [rdy].[Clock Observations], [rdy].[Radius Observations]
     , [Clock Observation Count] =  (len([rdy].[Clock Observations]) - len(replace([rdy].[Clock Observations],',',''))) / (len([rdy].[Clock Observations]) - len(replace([rdy].[Clock Observations],';','')) + 1) + 1
     , [Radius Observation Count] =  (len([Radius Observations]) - len(replace([Radius Observations],',',''))) / (len([Radius Observations]) - len(replace([Radius Observations],';','')) + 1) + 1
  from [cte_ReadyForDelimiting] [rdy]
) -- end [cte_CheckNumberOfColumns] 
, [cte_ParsingClockObservations] as (
select [src].[Emp_ID], [src].[Work Date], [src].[Clock Observations], [src].[Radius Observations]
       ,  [src].[Clock Observation Count] , [src].[Radius Observation Count]
       , [Clock Record Sequence] = [Times].[ItemNumber]
       , [Clock] = [Times].[Item]
from [cte_CountNumberOfSubColumns] [src]
  outer apply (select * from [tempDB].[dbo].[SplitAndSequence] ([src].[Clock Observations],','))  [Times]
) -- [cte_ParsingClockObservations] 
, [cte_ParsingRadiusObservations] as (
select [src].[Emp_ID], [src].[Work Date], [src].[Clock Observations], [src].[Radius Observations]
       ,  [src].[Clock Observation Count] , [src].[Radius Observation Count]
       , [Radius Record Sequence] = [Radius].[ItemNumber]
       , [Radius] = [Radius].[Item]
  from [cte_CountNumberOfSubColumns] [src]
  outer apply (select * from [tempDB].[dbo].[SplitAndSequence] ([src].[Radius Observations],','))  [Radius] --  on [Radius].[ItemNumber] = [Times].[ItemNumber]  */
 ) -- end [cte_ParsingRadiusObservations]
, [cte_TransposedRecords] as (
select [Emp_ID] = cast(isnull([times].[Emp_ID],[radius].[Emp_ID]) as varchar(10))
      , [Work Date] = isnull([times].[Work Date],[radius].[Work Date])
      , [Clock] = cast(case when isnull([times].[Clock],'N/A') in ('') then 'N/A' else isnull([times].[Clock],'N/A') end as varchar(10))
      , [Radius] = cast(case when isnull([radius].[Radius], 'N/A') in ('') then 'N/A' else isnull([radius].[Radius],'N/A') end as varchar(20))
      , [Stub] = 'StubStubStub'
      , [times].[Clock Record Sequence]
      , [radius].[Radius Record Sequence]
      , [times].[Clock Observations]
      , [times].[Radius Observations]
      , [times].[Clock Observation Count]
      , [times].[Radius Observation Count]
  from [cte_ParsingClockObservations] [times]
  full outer join [cte_ParsingRadiusObservations] [radius] on [radius].[Emp_ID] = [times].[Emp_ID] and [radius].[Work Date] = [times].[Work Date] and [radius].[Radius Record Sequence] = [times].[Clock Record Sequence] 
)
-- Original
select * from [cte_TransposedRecords]
```

Run a test with this line  of code (using the original enquiry data set)

```
select * from [fn_ParseAndReturnObservations]
   ('1234', 
   '12/10/2020', 
   'The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters')



Emp_ID     Work Date  Clock      Radius              
---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759              
1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758
```

**Step 4 Test Cases - and example usage**
Replace the last three lines of the test cases for the production table you want profiling with Clock times and radius re

```
with cte_SampleTests as (
    select TestCase = 'Original Case with a break down', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758 meters'
  union  select TestCase = 'Three Readings', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,209757 meters'
  union select TestCase = 'Forth Clock Position Listed but no value', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05, are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,209757,209755 meters' 
  union select TestCase = 'Four Radius and Three Clock Readings', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,209757,209755 meters'
  union select TestCase = 'Four Clock Readings and 3 Radius Readings', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05,12:06 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,209757 meters'
  union select TestCase = 'Four Clock Readings and Fourth Radius Reading missing', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05,12:06 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,209757, meters'
  union select TestCase = 'Four Clock Readings and third Radius Reading missing', [Test_Emp_ID] = '1234', [Test_WorkDateStr] = '12/10/2020', [Test_String] = 'The following clocks 12:03,12:04,12:05,12:06 are outside of the allowed radius by 209759,209758,,209757 meters'
)
select cte_SampleTests.[TestCase], x.*
      from [cte_SampleTests]
      cross apply (select * from [dbo].[fn_ParseAndReturnObservations]([cte_SampleTests].[Test_Emp_ID], [cte_SampleTests].[Test_WorkDateStr], [cte_SampleTests].[Test_String])) x

TestCase                                              Emp_ID     Work Date  Clock      Radius            
----------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------
Original Case with a break down                       1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Original Case with a break down                       1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Three Readings                                        1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Three Readings                                        1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Three Readings                                        1234       2020-10-12 12:05      209757            
Forth Clock Position Listed but no value              1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Forth Clock Position Listed but no value              1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Forth Clock Position Listed but no value              1234       2020-10-12 12:05      209757            
Forth Clock Position Listed but no value              1234       2020-10-12 N/A        209755            
Four Radius and Three Clock Readings                  1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Four Radius and Three Clock Readings                  1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Four Radius and Three Clock Readings                  1234       2020-10-12 12:05      209757            
Four Radius and Three Clock Readings                  1234       2020-10-12 N/A        209755            
Four Clock Readings and 3 Radius Readings             1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Four Clock Readings and 3 Radius Readings             1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Four Clock Readings and 3 Radius Readings             1234       2020-10-12 12:05      209757            
Four Clock Readings and 3 Radius Readings             1234       2020-10-12 12:06      N/A               
Four Clock Readings and Fourth Radius Reading missing 1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Four Clock Readings and Fourth Radius Reading missing 1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Four Clock Readings and Fourth Radius Reading missing 1234       2020-10-12 12:05      209757            
Four Clock Readings and Fourth Radius Reading missing 1234       2020-10-12 12:06      N/A               
Four Clock Readings and third Radius Reading missing  1234       2020-10-12 12:03      209759            
Four Clock Readings and third Radius Reading missing  1234       2020-10-12 12:04      209758            
Four Clock Readings and third Radius Reading missing  1234       2020-10-12 12:05      N/A               
Four Clock Readings and third Radius Reading missing  1234       2020-10-12 12:06      209757
```

**Step 5 - Modify the main function to hid all columns right of Column "Radius"**
Columns Stub and all to the right of Stub are listed to enable "workings" to be shown - - It may prove useful to have a the count of Radius and Clock observations for downstream analysis and decision profiling [Clock Record Sequence] and [Radius Record Sequence]

**Step 6 - go back to the original data author**
... and ask them to provide you an alternative structure - XML shouldn't be difficult